Checking QGZ/QGS 3.34.10 files in Notepad++
I noticed that in QGZ/QGS 3.34.10 files, some actions that should no longer exist in the QGIS project because they were deleted or edited are still present in the code, for example, "'Fotos/Risco_' || format_date(now(),'yyyyMMddhhmmsszzz') || '.jpg' " should no longer exist because it was replaced by another code. Checking the QGIS/QfieldSync options menu, I can't find the code, but editing QGS in Notepad++ I can. How can we clean or check the code? Is there any way to do this?
